# Is there API to get receive "pointer location" or "touch location" globally?

Tags: android

In ICS there's a new setting "Show pointer location". Is there API for it to get touch location data?

**EDIT:** sigh .. please assume that I am not trying to write malware.

Answer (score 3):

You can get your own touch location data in your own activities via methods like `onTouchEvent()`. You cannot get touch location data for other applications, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I understand the security implications, let's assume this is for internal, controlled environment use only (which in reality it is). Say I write a daemon, can you give me an idea of where to dig for the API I need to intercept touch location data? I apologize for the vagueness, I'm a bit of n00b in android, while being a developer for desktop and iOS for quite a while.

Comment: @YuriyGettya: AFAIK, there is no "API", per se. Touch event dispatching from the screen to an individual process would be buried somewhere in the OS source code, and I have no idea exactly where in the source code it would be. A "daemon" will likely be insufficient -- you're most likely looking at creating a custom build of Android and putting that into a modded ROM to run on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Comment from Google engineer on android-platform: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/_O-mZNasjj4/r6rKePd5u1YJ